# In Web UI Testing, is it possible to get the JSON response?

Tags: json, katalon-studio, jsonslurper

I am very new to Katalon Studio and had just a beginner experience using Jmeter. I  knew how to code JsonSlurper since I used it often when creating JMeter test scripts.

So is it possible to use JsonSlurper in a web UI test case in Katalon Studio? Or is it only possible in API testing? Please help TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do it. Katalon scripts are written in Groovy programming language so you can practically do whatever Groovy (or Java) can do:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def content = '{"data":[{"id":"1"},{"id": "2"}]}'
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
Map parsedJson = slurper.parseText(content)
```

Comment: I just put a general `content` as I didn't know what do you need. Just use whatever JSON you want in place of `content`.

Comment: I see, I saw a similar structure: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-parse-json-responses-in-katalon-studio. So I really need to define the `content`? The json response that I will get is structured as:`data[{id:..},{id:...}]`, and "id" count can be any number from 0 onward. Will I have a problem with that? Thanks again.

Comment: See the updated answer.  This is the way you can parse the JSON data, regardless of the content.